# How to use Spring Cloud Stream Kafka with Confluent Schema Registry?

Tags: spring, stream, registry, cloud, confluent-platform

I am seeking a simple workable example which use Spring Cloud Stream Kafka with Confluent Schema Registry (producer & consumer). I followed the [spring cloud stream reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_using_confluent_s_schema_registry) by adding the following code but it didn't work. Can anyone guide me how to achieve it? Many thanks!

```
@Bean
public SchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistryClient(@Value("${spring.cloud.stream.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint}") String endpoint){
  ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient client = new ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient();
  client.setEndpoint(endpoint);
  return client;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried [this schema registry sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/schema-registry-samples/schema-registry-confluent) and it worked for me. All instructions are mentioned in README file.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/charlbrink/cloud-stream-avro-sample) is a simple example that shows spring cloud stream with Avro serialization. This example stubs and mocks out the schema registry.

Your bean looks correct, you just need a running schema registry and configuration for "spring.cloud.stream.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint" in application.properties (or application.yml)